# GE historic stock price on DOD changed

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, death

My father owned GE stock and he died in November. In late November, for my appointment with the probate court, I looked up the closing stock price for the day he died. Unfortunately I downloaded the data instead of printing. Now I am working on the inventory for the court and need to provide the value of the stock on the day he died and provide documents supporting the valuation. But when I went to print off the historic stock price for the date of death, the value changed significantly. I assume this was caused by the spin-off of GEHC stock in December/January. But for my purposes, I can't use the post-spin off stock price because the spin-off had not occurred as of the date of death. Where can I get unadjusted historic stock prices?

Comment: Did you look here? https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/history?p=GE

Comment: @jesse_b good suggestion but I'm not sure I'd trust Yahoo Finance for official valuation purposes...

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD: I'm not sure why...yahoo finance is pretty much the gold standard for stock market information, but you can get the same information from any trading platform of your choice.

Comment: @jesse_b "gold standard" is a stretch... It's pretty good for a free resource but they're not immune to data quality issues.

Answer (score 20):

I'm sorry for your loss.

Where did he hold the stock? The broker should be able to provide the required statements.

If not, GE investor relations might be able to assist. Also, NYSE lists historical prices for stocks traded on it.

What price/value were you expecting?

Comment: +1 for investor relations - that'd be my first pick. Providing pre-split valuation is probably something a broker could also do.